# AngularJS with spring ModelAndView Ajax

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

I am sending a request from below jsp

```
<body ng-controller="MyController">     
<div data-role="page" class="container">
<%@ include file="header.jsp" %>
<div id="workingDiv"></div>
<%@ include file="footer.jsp" %>
</div>  
</body>
```

This is my Controller Code. We have update the working div using a diff jsp so I have used innerhtml to populate the result jsp into the working div . Please correct me if am wrong in doing this (using innerhtml) with Angular JS

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope,WidgetData) 
{
 WidgetData.get({
        id : '0'
    }).then(function(response){
        document.getElementById('workingDiv').innerHTML=response.data;

    });
});


app.factory('WidgetData', function($http){
return {
    get : function(params){
        return $http.get('getMainMenu.do', {
            params : params
        });
    }
 };
});
```

Java Spring Controller

```
    mav.setViewName("mainmenu");
    ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
    String json = ow.writeValueAsString(response);
    mav.addObject("details", json);
```

This is the result JSP

```
<div ng-init="details = [${details}]">
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="detail in details">
  {{detail}}
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I have to Assign the JSON Data from the ModelAndView to the scope, which am trying to do in the ng-init as above . .

```
{{details}}
```

I did a check to see if am getting the JSON data and it is having the correct data. But am getting the output as shown above.  Its only printing the text.Please correct me

Comment: You should never do DOM manipulation from controllers. Use angularJS templates and get JSON instead of HTML from your AJAX requests. Any angular tutorial covers that.

Comment: @JBNizet  Thanks for the response . I need to populate the data in my workingDIV dynamically . It may vary for every request. So in Anugular JS should we always only  get the JSON data and form the dynamic content in javascript.??.

Comment: Yes. That's how the framework is supposed to be used.